# How to set a mysql decimal value in java prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

How to set decimal value in java prepared statement.
I was tried as follows

My table query

`create table A (x decimal(22,0))`

In java I tried to set it as

```
preperedStatmentObj.setLong(1,aLongValue);
```

But i am getting the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your nagative points. Atleast give me a releated Stack overflow link. Thank you

Comment: why does the error gives give this message `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`? is `aLongValue` int?

Comment: Thank you.but i solved as follows pstmt.setObject(1, (Number)longValue);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using **[setBigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)**

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(aLongValue);
preperedStatmentObj.setBigDecimal(1, d);
```